# GraphQL Apollo Enum in Query

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

On the Server, I defined the enum and query in the schema:

```
type Query {
    hello: String!
    getData(dataType: DataType!): [DataPoint]
} 

enum DataType {
        ACCOUNT,
        USER,
        COMPANY
    }
...
```

On the Client:

```
export const GET_DATA = gql`
    query($dataType: DataType) {
        getData(dataType: $dataType) {
          ...
        }
    }
`;
```

Whenever I try calling the query in the ApolloClient I get a validation error since Apollo expects the value, not as a string, so instead of "ACCOUNT", it expects ACCOUNT. Trying to pass integer values obviously also doesn't do the trick.

```
  const dataResponse = useQuery(GET_DATA, {
       variables: { dataType: "ACCOUNT" },
  });
```

What would I need to change about the server or client-side implementation to be able to correctly pass the Enum value as a variable? Ideally, I would like to have the possibility to pass the string value into the useQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

On the client do:

```
export const GET_DATA = gql`
    query($dataType: String) {
        getData(dataType: $dataType) {
          ...
        }
    }
`;
```

This is because your enum is an enum of strings.